# video.js ended event

Tags: javascript, video.js

Why this throws up this error:

> The element or ID supplied is not valid. (VideoJS)

I know it may be obvious but there's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var videoPlayer = _V_("example_video_1", {}, function(){
this.addEvent("ended", function(){ 
   alert('Here I am');
  });
});        
</script>
```

and video ID set via PHP

```
<?PHP
  echo "<video id=\"example_video_1\" class=\"video-js vjs-default-skin\"  controls width=\"".$vid_h."\" height=\"".$vid_w."\" autoplay preload=\"auto\" data-setup='{}'>";
?>
```

Comment: is this the library used? https://github.com/zencoder/video-js

Comment: Please show the generated HTML, not the PHP code.

Comment: No - good point!generated - video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="240" height="320" autoplay preload="auto" data-setup='{}'>

Comment: No - I only have 
<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="video.js"></script>. PLEASE can you give me correct versions.

Comment: It's impossible to help if we don't know what library you're using. "video.js" couldn't be anything.

Comment: All sorted. It was the placing of the script that was the problem. Libraries used are <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="hd5.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your script is after the video element it references. Otherwise your get "the element or ID supplied is not valid" because it doesn't exist at the point the script executes.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="360" height="202" autoplay data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://example.com/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var videoPlayer = _V_("example_video_1", {}, function(){
      this.addEvent("ended", function(){ 
        alert('Here I am');
      });
    });       
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```